# Centos 6.4 2 NIC same gateway

Tags: networking, centos, nic, route

I'm having a problem with my centos server setup, i have 2 public nic and they have the ip from 209.59.252.0/24, with the same gateway. The problem is that only eth0 works, the other one doesn't. They have both the same configuration. Gateway is in /etc/sysconfig/network, also when i check the ip route show, i see the route for the eth2. Im using centos 6.4. Any ideea ?

Thanks,
Alin

Comment: You CANNOT use IP addresses from the same subnet on your server's NICs. Only one is allowed. You can do bonding and set one of the addresses to bonded interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its not clear from you question what you are trying to achieve. It sounds like your are trying to have one NIC as a backup to the other? If this is the case then you should check out NIC bonding: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/bonding.txt

This will allow you to create (amongst other things) A single active network link, backed up by an inactive one, or even bonding two NICS to create one "fat" link.

If you're not trying to acheive this, then please edit your question

Comment: Geo, Thanks but this i dont want bonding, maybe i didnt explain better, i dont have dhcp i have static ip addresess, when i put boding all my ip are gone, isn't there another way ? for example i have 3 whm with 8 ips and they are using the same gateway but no bonding.